# Web scraping, How to submit an aspx form in python 2.7?

Tags: asp.net, python-2.7, web-scraping

I'm learning web scraping but I can't login to a webpage that uses aspx, its form tag is:

`<`form name="Form1" method="post" action="CmrcLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fCMRC%2fcmrcMain.aspx" id="Form1">

the username and password input text boxes are:

```
<input name="tbxUserID" type="text" maxlength="50" id="tbxUserID" tabindex="1" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;width:256px;">
```

and

```
<input name="txtPassword" type="password" maxlength="15" id="txtPassword" tabindex="1" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt;width:256px;">
```

but the Login Button is type=image and calls some javacript

```
<input type="image" name="BtnLogin" onclick="if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate(); " language="javascript" id="BtnLogin" tabindex="2" src="Images/BtnLogin.jpg" alt="" border="0">
```

So, how do you submit a form like this that has a Button type=image and executes a JavaScript function? So far, I have tried with mechanize, urllib and urllib2 python 2.7 libraries.

I tried to login using mechanize but looks like it only works with HTML forms? Also the "action" property of the form is not a normal web address so it didn't work with urllib2.urlopen(). Filling the username and password is not the problem but submitting it. I'm new to web scraping and the tutorials I have read so far don't address this particular issue.

P.D.
I didn't give the whole html code because the webpage I'm working on is in an intranet and is very verbose, but I can post it upon request.

Comment: Unsure if you're asking how to submit a form in general, or are you saying you're trying to submit a form to an ASP.Net site (from an external app or something)? If it's the latter, well, you'll have issues related to POSTback protections (anti-spoof) in ASP.Net

Comment: It's specific to aspx sites. Is there a workaround or a PyPI package to solve this issue? I'm sure someone has solved this problem before. Thanks.

Comment: [VIEWSTATE and EVENTVALIDATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163512.aspx#S3) won't let you spoof asp.net postback (assuming it's configured properly)...